# Ler tabela em Lua através do C++

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

Eu tenho uma tabela em Lua desse jeito:

```
myTable={
  one = {a=1, b=2, c=3},
  two = {a=4, b=2, c=1}
}
```

O arquivo já foi carregado, como faço para ler os dados da tabela através do C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Achei na [lista de usuário de Lua](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-04/msg00201.html) este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {
    #include "lua/lua.h"
    #include "lua/lualib.h"
    #include "lua/lauxlib.h"
}
// In Lua 5.0 reference manual is a table traversal example at page 29.
void PrintTable(lua_State *L) {
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while(lua_next(L, -2) != 0) {
        if(lua_isstring(L, -1))
          printf("%s = %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -2), lua_tostring(L, -1));
        else if(lua_isnumber(L, -1))
          printf("%s = %d\n", lua_tostring(L, -2), lua_tonumber(L, -1));
        else if(lua_istable(L, -1))
          PrintTable(L);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
}

void main() {
    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    // Load file.
    if(luaL_loadfile(L, "seuCodigo.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)) {
        printf("Cannot run file\n");
        return;
    }
    // Print table contents.
    lua_getglobal(L, "myTable");
    PrintTable(L);
    // Print specific field.
    lua_getglobal(L, "myTable");
    lua_pushstring(L, "one");
    lua_gettable(L, -2);
    if(lua_isstring(L, -1))
        printf("\myTable.one = %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    lua_close(L);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/ReadTableInC.cpp).

É provável que você tenha que adaptar ao que você quer mas já é um começo considerando que você não tinha nada feito.

- [Quick reference da API](http://www.ewald-arnold.de/lua/lua_capi.pdf).
- [Entendendo a API](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html).
- [Resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27039351/221800).