# Como ler uma tabela lua em C da seguinte forma

Tags: lua

Bem estou tentando criar uma leitura em lua que consiga ler essa tabela abaixo,  a tabela só deve aceitar valores e caso adicionem string, ele avisa o local do erro.

```
Table = {
        1000,       2000,       3000,       4000,       5000,
        6000,       7000,       8000,       9000,       10000,
        11111,      12000,      13000,      14000,      15000,..
}
```

Estou o código está da seguinte forma:

```
void read_table(void) {

    int var1;
    long double var2;
    lua_State *L;
    L = = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "table.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)) {
        printf("cannot run cofig file: %s\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        lua_getfield(L, -1, "Table");

        if (lua_type(L, -1) == 5) {
            var1 = 1;
            while (1)
            {
                lua_pushnumber(L, var2);
                lua_gettable(L, -2);

                if (!lua_isnumber(L, -1))
                break;
                lua_tonumber(L, -1);
                lua_settop(L, -2);
                ++var1;

                lua_close(L);
            }
            printf("table %d invalid\n", var1);
        }
        else {
            printf("table should be a table\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Reading %d numbers\n", var1);
}
```

Como posso fazer para ler essa tabela, estou começando a aprender lua agora.

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta direito. Qual é o problema que você está tendo com o seu código atual?

Comment: Aparece o seguinte erro na hora da leitura, PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API

Comment: Em que linha acontece o erro? (se você nâo souber, você pode rodar o programa C num debugador para descobrir)

Comment: Não fala qual a linha.

Comment: Você sabe usar algum debugador para C, eles dizem a linha do erro pra você. Qual sistema operacional / IDE vc está usando?

Comment: Usei aqui e me apontou aqui. `lua_getfield(L, -1, "Table");` Então esse código Table = ae fica dentro do arquivo table.lua, eu estou tentando fazer ele ler os valores ali da tabela.

Comment: Veja se isto te ajuda de alguma forma: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55230/101

Comment: Eu tentei usando esse, mais sem sucesso

Answer (score 1):

Use `lua_getglobal(L, "Table")` em vez de `lua_getfield(L, -1, "Table")`.

Considere usar `luaL_dofile` em vez de `luaL_loadfile + lua_pcall`.

Comment: Consegui fazer a leitura, porém encontrei um problema, ele faz a leitura de cada valor, agora queria saber como posso printar cada valor que está sendo lido, pois a var1 está printando a quantidade apenas. Aqui o código, ficou grande então estou postando o link http://pastebin.com/sYWkthn1